# Validating using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I am trying to validate this simple quiz using Javascript. The idea is to warn the user when they forget an input when submitting the quiz.

I would like an alert to pop up:

1. When the text is missing,
2. When the text entered is more than 3 characters,
3. When the text is not a yes or no, when one of the choices offered has not been marked (for both radio and checkbox input).

I will include both the form and the JavaScript below to go with this, as I find it necessary to understand the issue(s).

```
    <form name="quiz" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
                <ul>
                    <li><label id="web">Do you ever think about how you would design a web page?</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="no" name="rad1"/><span>No</span></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="yes" name="rad2"/><span>Yes</span></li>
                    <li><label for="check">Which the following are your main priorities? If none, please check N/A</label> </li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op1"/><span>Ease of Use</span></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op2" value="op2"/> <span>Graphics & Content</span></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op3" value="op3"/><span> The Data Collected</span></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op4" value="op4"/><span>Securing the site from possible attacks</span></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op2" value="op2"/><span>N/A</span></li>
                    <li><label id="res">Do you enjoy conducting research, asking questions, and building reports?</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="no" name="rad3"/><span>No</span></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="yes" name="rad4"/><span>Yes</span></li>
                    <li><label for="text1">Does hacking a system or stopping a system from being hacked sound interesting to you? Type Yes or No:</label></li>
                    <li><textarea name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="3"></textarea></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Finished!" id="submit"></li>
                    <li><input type="reset" id="reset"></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var radio1 = document.quiz.rad1;
        var radio2 = document.quiz.rad2;
        var ch1 = document.quiz.op1;
        var ch2 = document.quiz.op2;
        var ch3 = document.quiz.op3;
        var ch4 = document.quiz.op4;
        var ch5 = document.quiz.op5;
        var radio3 = document.quiz.rad3;
        var radio4 = document.quiz.rad4;
        var tx1 = document.quiz.text1;
        function vWebRes(radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4){
            x=0;
            if(radio1.checked) || (radio2.checked) || (radio3.checked) || (radio4.checked) {
                x++;
            }
            if (x==0) {
                alert('You forgot a question!')
                radio1.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert('Completed!');
                window.location.reload()
                return true;
            }
        }
        function vCheck(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5){
            y=0;
            if(ch1.checked) || (ch2.checked) || (ch3.checked) || (ch4.checked) || (ch5.checked){
                y++;
            }
            if (y==0) {
                alert('You forgot a question!')
                radio1.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert('Completed!');
                window.location.reload()
                return true;
            }
        }
        function vLenght(tx1) {
            var txLength = tx.value.length;
            if (txLength == 0 || txLength < 3) {
                alert("That is an incorrect entry, try again.")
                txLength.focus();
                return false
            }
            else {
                return true
            }
        }
        function vCheck(tx1) {
            if (tx1 == Yes && tx1 == YES && tx1 == yes) || (tx1 == No && tx1 == NO && tx1 == no) {
                tx1.focus();
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The first step you should always take when debugging javascript is to check the console for errors. Dropping you code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgbfaw54/) shows that you have an "Unexprected token" error. The fiddle even highlights that for you. You should try and resolve that error yourself, id you can't then ask a question, reporting any errors from the console.

Comment: A further issue is that you never actually call the internal functions, only declare them.

Comment: @JonP I am a beginner with JavaScript and am writing it in Brackets; I have no idea what jsfiddle is, but I will check it out. I have been trying to resolve this for 3 days now. I rewrote it a few times and couldn't figure out what was wrong, this is why I turned to stackoverflow. Although it may not seem like it, I did try. A user below helped me out quite a bit and actually helped me correct my errors.

Comment: I am actually trying to help, the console is your debugging friend. You access from the browser using the browser tools (F12 in most browsers). When asking a question on StackOverflow it's always helpful to report any errors you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<form name="quiz" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <ul>
        <li><label id="web">Do you ever think about how you would design a web page?</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="no" name="rad1" /><span>No</span></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="yes" name="rad2" /><span>Yes</span></li>
        <li><label for="check">Which the following are your main priorities? If none, please check N/A</label> </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op1" /><span>Ease of Use</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="op2" value="op2" /> <span>Graphics & Content</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="op3" value="op3" /><span> The Data Collected</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="op4" value="op4" /><span>Securing the site from possible attacks</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="op2" value="op2" /><span>N/A</span></li>
        <li><label id="res">Do you enjoy conducting research, asking questions, and building reports?</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="no" name="rad3" /><span>No</span></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="yes" name="rad4" /><span>Yes</span></li>
        <li><label for="text1">Does hacking a system or stopping a system from being hacked sound interesting to you? Type Yes or No:</label></li>
        <!-- <li><textarea name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="3"></textarea></li> -->
        <!-- maxlength changed to higher value or remove it because it is meant to be a paragraph-->
        <li><textarea name="text1" id="text1"></textarea></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Finished!" id="submit"></li>
        <li><input type="reset" id="reset"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var radio1 = document.quiz.rad1;
        var radio2 = document.quiz.rad2;
        var ch1 = document.quiz.op1;
        var ch2 = document.quiz.op2;
        var ch3 = document.quiz.op3;
        var ch4 = document.quiz.op4;
        var ch5 = document.quiz.op5;
        var radio3 = document.quiz.rad3;
        var radio4 = document.quiz.rad4;
        var tx1 = document.quiz.text1;

        //call these functions in order to validate
        vWebRes(radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4);
        vCheck(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5);
        //document.getElementById() gets the HTML element object according to id in <textarea ... id="text1" ...></textarea>
        vLength(document.getElementById('text1'));



        function vWebRes(radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4) {
            x = 0;
            //inserted missing braces
            if ((radio1.checked) || (radio2.checked) || (radio3.checked) || (radio4.checked)) {
                x++;
            }
            if (x == 0) {
                alert('You forgot a question!')
                radio1.focus();
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('Completed!');
                window.location.reload()
                return true;
            }
        }

        function vCheck(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5) {
            y = 0;
            //inserted missing braces
            if ((ch1.checked) || (ch2.checked) || (ch3.checked) || (ch4.checked) || (ch5.checked)) {
                y++;
            }
            if (y == 0) {
                alert('You forgot a question!')
                radio1.focus();
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('Completed!');
                window.location.reload()
                return true;
            }
        }
        // corrected spelling vLenght to vLength
        function vLength(tx1) {
            // fixed tx to tx1
            // var txLength = tx.value.length;
            var txLength = tx1.value.length;
            if (txLength == 0 || txLength < 3) {
                alert("That is an incorrect entry, try again.")
                    //removed the following function because there is no access to the HTML input field unless you would like to add it
                    //txLength.focus();
                tx1.focus();
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }


        /*
        renamed second vCheck to vCheck2
        this function is just a confusion that overwrites the first vCheck because this function serves nothing useful but fixed anyway
        */

        function vCheck2(tx1) {
            //inserted missing braces
            //in this case, tx1 compares the value '==' as string 
            if ((tx1 == "Yes" && tx1 == "YES" && tx1 == "yes") || (tx1 == "No" && tx1 == "NO" && tx1 == "no")) {
                tx1.focus();
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
//good luck
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping a beginner! The comments you added helped a ton. Along the way I also figured out other logical errors I had made and now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vastly simplified version:

```js
function validateForm() {

  //Use query selector all to get the humber of checked check boxes
  var numChChecked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name=op1]:checked").length;

  var numRad1Checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio][name=rad1]:checked").length;

  var numRad2Checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio][name=rad2]:checked").length;

  var text = document.getElementById("text1");

  //Check there is atleast 1 Checkbox checked
  if (numChChecked == 0) {
    alert("You missed a question")
    document.quiz.op1[0].focus();
    return false;
  }


  //Check there is atleast 1 radio button checked
  if (numRad1Checked + numRad2Checked === 0) {
    alert("You missed a question");
    document.quiz.rad1[0].focus();
    return false;
  }

  //Check the text length
  if (text.value.length > 3 || text.value.length === 0) {
    alert("Invalid response length");
    text.focus();
    return false;
  }

  //Nortmalise the case to lower case to simplyfy the check
  //also note the " this denotes a string.
  if (!(text.value.toLowerCase() === "yes" || text.value.toLowerCase() === "no")) {
    alert("Invalid response");
    text.focus();
    return false;
  }

  alert("Success");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="quiz" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
  <ul>
    <li><label id="web">Do you ever think about how you would design a web page?</label></li>
    <!-- note the radio buttons must have the same name if you want to 
    toggle between them -->
    <li><input type="radio" value="no" name="rad1" /><span>No</span></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="yes" name="rad1" /><span>Yes</span></li>
    <li><label for="check">Which the following are your main priorities? If none, please check N/A</label> </li>
    <!-- If these are a groupm they probably should have the same name -->
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op1" /><span>Ease of Use</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op2" /> <span>Graphics & Content</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op3" /><span> The Data Collected</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op4" /><span>Securing the site from possible attacks</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="op1" value="op2" /><span>N/A</span></li>
    <li><label id="res">Do you enjoy conducting research, asking questions, and building reports?</label></li>
    <!-- note the radio buttons must have the same name if you want to 
    toggle between them -->
    <li><input type="radio" value="no" name="rad3" /><span>No</span></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="yes" name="rad3" /><span>Yes</span></li>
    <li><label for="text1">Does hacking a system or stopping a system from being hacked sound interesting to you? Type Yes or No:</label></li>
    <li><textarea name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="4"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Finished!" id="submit"></li>
    <li><input type="reset" id="reset"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Note you have some problems with your HTML. Groups of radio buttons or checkboxes should have the same name

For more info on some to the techniques I've used above see:

1. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which has important differences to [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
3. [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
4. [Check Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)
5. [The `:checked` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)
6. [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 0):

You have missing braces for your if statements and functions inside are unnecessary. Your js code should be:

```
function validateForm() {
    var radio1 = document.quiz.rad1;
    var radio2 = document.quiz.rad2;
    var ch1 = document.quiz.op1;
    var ch2 = document.quiz.op2;
    var ch3 = document.quiz.op3;
    var ch4 = document.quiz.op4;
    var ch5 = document.quiz.op5;
    var radio3 = document.quiz.rad3;
    var radio4 = document.quiz.rad4;
    var tx1 = document.quiz.text1;

  x=0;
  if(radio1.checked || radio2.checked || radio3.checked || radio4.checked) {
    x++;
  }
  if (x==0) {
    alert('You forgot a question!')
    radio1.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else {
    alert('Completed!');
    window.location.reload()
    return true;
  }

  y=0;
  if(ch1.checked || ch2.checked || ch3.checked || ch4.checked || ch5.checked){
    y++;
  }
  if (y==0) {
    alert('You forgot a question!')
    radio1.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else {
    alert('Completed!');
    window.location.reload()
    return true;
  }

  var txLength = tx.value.length;
  if (txLength == 0 || txLength < 3) {
    alert("That is an incorrect entry, try again.")
    txLength.focus();
    return false
  }
  else {
    return true
  }

  if ((tx1 == Yes && tx1 == YES && tx1 == yes) || (tx1 == No && tx1 == NO && tx1 == no)) {
    tx1.focus();
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```